# Websocket waiting for message with Timeout

Tags: go

I want to create a Websocket connection via GO. This connection follows a clearly defined pattern: The client should "authenticate" (enter data) themself immediately after creating the connection. If the client does not do it, the connection will be closed after a short period.

My current code contains this initial timeout (initTimeout) and the maximum timeout for all connections. While those timers can easily be checked, i am not sure how i can combine the timers with waiting for a message which blocks the execution.

```
ws, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
initTimeout := time.NewTicker(time.Duration(30) * time.Second)
maxTimeout := time.NewTicker(time.Duration(45) * time.Minute)

for {
    select {
        case <- initTimeout.C:
            ws.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte("No input received"))
            ws.Close()
        case <- maxTimeout.C:
            ws.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte("Maximum timeout"))
            ws.Close()
        default:
            mt, message, err := c.ReadMessage()
            // will this block the timers?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [read deadline](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Conn.SetReadDeadline) to implement the timeouts:

```
ws, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}

// Read the initial message with deadline of 30 seconds
ws.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(30 * time.Second))
mt, message, err := ws.ReadMessage()
if err != nil {
   // Handle the error which might be a deadline exceeded error.
}
// process the initial message
// ...

for {
    // Read next message with deadline of 45 minutes
    ws.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(45 * time.Minute))
    mt, message, err = ws.ReadMessage()
    if err != nil {
        // Handle the error which might be a deadline exceeded error.
    }
    // process message
     // ....
}
```